# How to display count of rows in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I am a cocoa newbie so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

I have a NSTableView that is being populated by a OpenPanel and all works ok.

Now I'd like to show the number of items in the NSTableView in a NSTextField. How do I get the number of items of the NSTableView? Do I use numberOfRowsInTableView?

Also, as a followup, what is the ideal way to catch updates to the NSTableView regardless how they happen, either from File Menu, Toolbar or drap and drop?

Thanks.

Comment: Could You show some code You've already written, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is just to ask your datasource.
Your datasource is usually an array inside a view controller or at least an object that is a delegate to your tableview.

```
[anArray count];
```

Gives you an integer. Given that you have hooked up your textfield, this is what you need :

```
myTextfield.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [anArray count]];
```

Simple as that.

Comment: Thanks that was it. I've also solved my second question.

`-(void)updateTableViewCounter;

-(void)updateTableViewCounter { 
 NSString *fieldText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d item(s) in list", [TableData count]];
 [statusTextField setStringValue:fieldText]; 
}

-(void)createItem:(NSString *)filePath {
[self updateTableViewCounter];

Comment: Here is the code again....

`-(void)updateTableViewCounter;

-(void)updateTableViewCounter { 
 NSString *fieldText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d item(s) in list", [TableData count]];
 [statusTextField setStringValue:fieldText]; 
}

-(void)createItem:(NSString *)filePath {
 ...
 [self updateTableViewCounter];
 ...
}

- (IBAction)deleteRow:(id)sender {
 ...
[self updateTableViewCounter];
 ...
}
`